# How to fix the dot (.) based on hint

Tags: android

I am stuck with the logic

```
lEditText.setHint("CCCC.CC");
here CCCC.CC is the currency
```

Like calculator  entry entry should take from right to left, 
This one can be done by

```
lEditText.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

But my question:

I wanted to enter 123
during type only it should validate and put dot at 3rd position from last

if I enter 1, it should show as .01

if I enter 2, it should show as .12

if I enter 3, it should show as 1.23.

Can some body guide how to approach this one? 
Thanks

Comment: Can you be little bit more clear? you can place dot as per (enteredText/100). Can't you?

Answer (score 4):

You can implement a `TextWatcher` and implement your functionality in `afterTextChanged`. Set the `TextWatcher` on the `TextView` using `addTextChangedListener`

Comment: Thanks, I tried for other of my requirements, but for above question FlamePrincess answer holds good.

Comment: It's ok. Glad I could help